# Wordpress : Redirect when user is logged in & on login page

Tags: wordpress, redirect, authentication

I'm tring to redirect my logged users supposing that they will somehow end up on the login page (Redirection to the member area).

Here is my code, located in my functions.php file :

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() && is_page(ID) ) {
    wp_redirect('mydomain.com/my-member-area/');
    exit;
}
```

So, I tried putting the page ID, or the slug between '', but it won't work.

And when I remove the `&& is_page(ID)` part, redirection works on every single page (logically).

Comment: I started with 'Hello everyone', but it looked like it disappeared !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() && get_the_ID() == 6005 ) {
    wp_redirect('mydomain.com/my-member-area/');
    exit;
}
```

Comment: I tried it this morning, still not working. But thanks anyway !

What i'm looking for is : is the user logged ? is he on page id 6005 ? if both then redirect to members area.

Comment: sorry i forgot to put the id in there.  try it now.

Comment: Hi, i tried this but it still didn't work, so i tried something to see where i was wrong, now here it is :

When I edit my post or look in the code the id is 6005, and when i try is_page(6005), nothing happens, but if i try !is_page(6005), then the page is redirected.

So something is really going wrong because it would mean that page id is not 6005 but it's clearly written 6005 !

Comment: is this inside a hook within functions.php?

Answer (score 12):

All answer here did not work for me, This worked for me:

```
function add_login_check()
{
    if (is_user_logged_in()) {
        if (is_page(6005)){
            wp_redirect('mydomain.com/my-member-area/');
            exit; 
        }
    }
}

add_action('wp', 'add_login_check');
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved, thanks to Manishie !

My function wasn't hooked, my bad ! I wasn't seeing this obviously !

So here is my working code now :

```
function add_login_check()
{
    if ( is_user_logged_in() && is_page(6005) ) {
        wp_redirect('mydomain.com/my-member-area/');
        exit;
    }
}

add_action('wp', 'add_login_check');
```

You made my day ! Thank you Manishie.

Answer (score 0):

```
function add_login_check()
{
    if ( is_user_logged_in() && is_page(6005) ) {
        wp_redirect('mydomain.com/my-member-area/');
        exit;
    }
}
add_action('wp', 'add_login_check');
```

Comment: It's better to add description about the answer, so it'll help others to better understand your answer

Answer (score 0):

Thing is, using a page ID through the `is_page` statement is an hacky way, not suitable for production.

Additionally using the [`wp`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp/) action will be called on every page as it fires once the WordPress environment has been set up... A much better approach would be to use [`login_init`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/login_init/) which only fires when the login form is initialized.

This is based on the assumption that you are still using the default WordPress login system. If a user is already logged in and visit a `wp-login.php` page, the redirect will fire and push him to the profile page.

We also need to ignore the logout url as it will prevent the user from disconnecting, we will be using `str_contains` to ignore any url containing `wp-login.php?action=logout`.

```
/**
 * Redirect to the profile page if the user is already logged in
 * 
 * @param NULL
 * @return NULL
 */
add_action( 'login_init', 'redirect_to_the_profile_page_if_the_user_is_already_logged_in' );

function redirect_to_the_profile_page_if_the_user_is_already_logged_in() {

    if ( is_user_logged_in() && ! str_contains( basename( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ), 'wp-login.php?action=logout' ) ) {

        $user_id = get_current_user_id();

        $location = get_author_posts_url( $user_id );
       
        wp_safe_redirect( $location );

        exit;

    };

};
```